# how to test gwt requestbuilder with junit in gwttestcase?

Tags: java, gwt, junit, xmlhttprequest

My GWT app contains data which must be read out from xml-files which are on the client side.
For this i am using RequestBuilder.

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET,GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"myFile.xml");
```

try{
builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
       @Override
       public void onResponseReceived(Request request,Response response) {

```
       // read out data and put into to a list

   }
```

});
.........

The data will be read out put it into an list and from this list the datas will be put into to the view.
How to test this?
When i try this in the GWTTestCase class with some assertEquals methods inside the onResponseReceived  i get this error-message:

> [WARN] 404 - GET /com.test.app.appName.JUnit/myFile.xml (192.168.2.102) 1466 bytes
>      Request headers
>         Host: 192.168.2.102:51731
>         User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 Firefox/3.0.19
>         Accept-Language: en-us
>         Accept: */*
>         Connection: Keep-Alive
>         Referer: h t t_p://192.168.2.102:51731/com.test.app.appName.JUnit/junit-standards.html?gwt.codesvr=192.168.2.102:51727
>         Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>      Response headers
>         Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>         Content-Length: 1466

What i am doing wrong?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow up with GWT Test code for RequestBuilder available in their source code. You can search as [RequestBuilder](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/search?q=RequestBuilderTest&origq=RequestBuilderTest&btnG=Search+Trunk) test cases.

Also in your case you might be best served to just use mocking to avoid slowing down test cases.